# Groovy string contains function not working in Labvantage LIMS

Tags: groovy, contains

We have a lab system to manage calculations within our lab, called Labvantage. Calculations are based on Groovy, but when text seems to come in of them, I'm stuck.

I try to do a calculation that if you enter a result which contains a smaller than sign, it takes this over in the calculation. E.g. what I want to do is dividing entered values by 1000:

1 becomes 0.001

<1 becomes <0.001

**Edit: found working code after a few hours of trying & searching on Google:**

```
def convertLimit(String x) { x.contains('<') ? ('<' + Double.parseDouble(x - '<')/1000) : (Double.parseDouble(x)/1000) } 

convertLimit(${Al;Standard;*;enteredtext})
```

Comment: Any minimal working example?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I currently have
String.valueOf(${Al;Standard}).contains('<') ? ('<'+(${Al;Standard}).find( /-?\d+\.\d*|-?\d*\.\d+|-?\d+/ ).toDouble()/1000) : (Double.parseDouble(${Al;Standard})/1000) but now get the error Calculation Failed. Error message: Expression Error: No signature of method: java.lang.String.find() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: {"-?\d+\.\d*|-?\d*\.\d+|-?\d+"} when evaluating: $G{String.valueOf(params.p0).contains('<') ? ('<'+(params.p0).find( /-?\d+\.\d*|-?\d*\.\d+|-?\d+/ ).toDouble()/1000) : (Double.parseDouble(params.p0)/1000) }